# Olark like software in node.js needed

Tags: node.js, chat, user-input, livechat

Do you know any node.js application that do something similar to http://olark.com. Not necessarily for multiple website, I just need it for single domain.
I just want to install it myself on heroku and run chat customer support for my website on it.

Thanks,

Michal

Comment: If you already know a solution, why do you want it to be redone in a different language and environment?

Comment: I want to be able to run it for free off heroku for example

Answer (score 3):

Try out [opensource-olark](https://github.com/alagu/opensource-olark/). I built it for my own use - it may be useful to you. It is not entirely based on Nodejs. But it works exactly like Olark. It uses strophe.js - A xmpp push based library for jabber which works with [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html)

Comment: Thank you for building this and making it available!

Comment: Does it provide chat queue functionality? I mean if the agent is busy incoming requests are kept in queue. Can you please guide me how can I implement it? XMPP site does not recommend the use of workgroup protocol. can you suggest any alternative?

Comment: Queuing is not supported yet. When an agent is busy, usual protocol is to show a message window (from, subject, message)

Answer (score 1):

try http://www.vivocha.com, based on node.js

It's very symple to use and you can integrate with other applications via API (with CRMs and ticketing systems for exemple).

This platform, with only one line of code on your website, allow you to configure all the widgets, without other tech skills needed.

And also, you can adding voice on your website, so you can call with your visitors directly on your web pages.

Answer (score 0):

There are open source tools that you can check out like :

- http://nowjs.com
- http://www.socketstream.org

They allow you to incorporate realtime features into your nodejs app & you can probably have a very simplified olark-type app in just a couple lines of code.